# On the divisor function in a summation

Tags: nt.number-theory, mobius-inversion

I want to compute the limit inferior and superior of the following sum
$$f(x):=\sum_{\substack{d \leq x\\P^+(d)\le\sqrt{x}}} \mu(d)\tau(d)\left[\frac{x}{d}\right]$$

Where $μ$ is the Mobius function, $τ$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$,  $h(x)=[x]$ is the floor function  and $P^{+}(d)$ is the largest prime divisor of $d≥2$, and $P^{+}(1)=0$.